# Conditional text in RMarkdown using multiple variables

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have a scenario where I am writing a report in R Markdown and I want text to appear based on the values of 3 different variables. In the example below, I want the text to appear if *a* is greater than *b* and *c*. I have found out that you use eval but Ive only managed to use this with 2 variables as shown in the code below. How do I amend the eval part below to include *a*, *b* and *c*?

````
a<-6
b<-3
c<-2


```{r conditional_block, echo=FALSE, results='asis', eval=a>b}
cat("6 is greater than 3 and is greater than 2")
```
````

Comment: Just do `a>b & a>c`

Comment: @MartinSchmelzer Thanks Martin!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any kind of conditional logic within the chunk option. If you have more than one condition which needs to be met, you can use the `&` symbol between them which will require both to be TRUE. Here is a basic example:

```
a<-6
b<-3
c<-2

a>b & a>c
```

> TRUE

```
# Make a less than c but bigger than b
a <- 2.5
a>b & a>c
```

> FALSE

If you want to find out more about the use of operators in R, I recommend this page: https://www.statmethods.net/management/operators.html